# こと as an Imperative

Tags: grammar, imperatives, particle-こと

I just came across the grammar being metioned here http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-koto/.
It states yet another way to form the imperative.

To my surprise I cannot find any related info for this on google.
I already know three other ways on how to form the imperative. Where exactly does こと fit in?

- ?: Verb + こと

  > お金を大切にすること。
- Command: Verb-stem+なさい

  > お金を大切にしなさい。
- More straight forward/abrupt

  > お金を大切にしろ。
- Request: てください

  > お金を大切にしてください。

One difference I noticed is that you can use こと for both positive and negative verbs which makes it really convenient. Unlike with the others, where you would have to use

> するな

or

> しないでください

respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「Verb in Dictionary Form (Affirmative or Negative) + **こと**」

is a valid and very common way of forming an imperative.  We all grow up hearing this imperative form used by our teachers, parents, older kids, etc.  It is ***that*** kind of strict imperative; It is not a friendly request.  You have no choice but to obey. ♡

This 「こと」 is a ***sentence-ending particle*** and it should be treated differently from [the noun 「こと/事」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BA%8B-502856#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88).  You will find this usage of 「こと」 in every monolingual dictionary.  Read (if you could) where it says 終助{しゅうじょ}, which means "sentence-ending particle" here for instance: [「こと」in 大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-65466#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)

---

List of karate school rules found on the Internet:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to "A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar", page 135:

> こと: an auxiliary noun to express a command.
>   It is used only in written Japanese.
>   They often appear in rules and regulations.
>
> Examples:
>   私語は慎むこと。
>   Refrain from whispering.
>
> 先に必ずテープを聞くこと。
>   Be sure to listen to the tape beforehand.