# What is the meaning and utility of the "Koto" in the end of these five Karate-Do Principles?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

The Japanese martial art Karate-Do has five principles on conduct that should be pursued by its practitioners. In all books it comes with the `koto` at its end, just after the principal verb. I've read that `koto` means `thing`, and in other source I've read that `koto` after a verb makes it transform to a noun verb, but I think I've don't really understood that very well, since I can't understand the use of `koto` in this five phrases:

```
一、人格 完成に 努める こと
hitotsu, jinkaku kansei ni tsutomeru koto
Exert yourself in the perfection of character


一、誠の道を守ること
hitotsu, makoto no michi wo mamoru koto
Be faithful and sincere


一、努力の精神を養うこと
hitotsu, doryoku no seishin wo yashinau koto
Cultivate the spirit of perseverance


一、礼儀を重んずること
hitotsu, reigi wo omonzuru koto
Respect propriety


一、血気の勇を戒むること
hitotsu, kekki no yū wo imashimuru koto
Refrain from impetuous and violent behaviour
```

These were extract from this site: http://www.shotokankaratedoassociation.com/translating-dojo-kun-meaning-behind-japanese-characters/ where they explain the philosophical meaning of the principles.

But, from the grammatical point-of-view, I didn't understood it. What is the meaning and the utility of this `koto`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41195/9831